# PHP - same value in mysqli bind param

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can I optimize this code ?

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "iiiiiii", $user, $user, $user, $user, $user, $user, $user);
```

Used for this request :

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT u_id, u_lastname, u_firstname, 
    (SELECT f_id from friend where (f_friend_one = u_id AND f_friend_two = ?) OR (f_friend_one = ? AND f_friend_two = u_id)),
    (SELECT f_type from friend where (f_friend_one = u_id AND f_friend_two = ?) OR (f_friend_one = ? AND f_friend_two = u_id))
FROM    user
WHERE   (( u_id = ( SELECT f_friend_one FROM friend WHERE f_friend_one = u_id AND f_friend_two = ? AND (f_type = 1 OR f_type = 4))) 
OR      ( u_id = ( SELECT f_friend_two FROM friend WHERE f_friend_one = ? AND f_friend_two = u_id AND (f_type = 1 OR f_type = 3))))
AND     u_id != ? ")
    or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: Probably won't make a difference in run time, but I'm sure you could shorten the query, however, since it's not included...

Comment: The query could probably be simplified into a `JOIN` so you don't have to repeat all those queries. I'm trying to figure out what it's doing.

Comment: The query get the friend informations if they are friend : I have a friend table with three columns : id, f_friend_one (the user who send invitation), f_friend_two.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify it to this:

```
SELECT u_id, u_lastname, f_id, f_type
FROM user
JOIN friend
    ON (u_id = f_friend_one AND f_friend_two = ? AND f_type IN (1, 4))
        OR
       (u_id = f_friend_two AND f_friend_one = ? AND f_type IN (1, 3))
WHERE u_id != ?
```

It's possible that the `WHERE` clause at the end isn't needed, since someone can't send a friend request to themselves.

The `OR` may make this hard for MySQL to optimize, so it may be better to split it into two subqueries connected with `UNION`.

```
SELECT u_id, u_lastname, f_id, f_type
FROM user
JOIN friend ON u_id = f_friend_one
WHERE f_friend_two = ? AND f_type IN (1, 4))
    AND u_id != ?

UNION

SELECT u_id, u_lastname, f_id, f_type
FROM user
JOIN friend ON u_id = f_friend_two
WHERE f_friend_one = ? AND f_type IN (1, 3))
    AND u_id != ?
```